# How to restore removed item from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a users card list, my task is:

Clicking "undo" button: will restore the last card that was deleted (use array)

Question 1: How to make array from cards list I have displayed ?
Question 2: How to restore the last card that was deleted? 
(IF 2 cards are removed, "undo" button will to restore card one by one)

Link to codepen here https://codepen.io/MarinaShumeiko/pen/Nbeqew?editors=1010

```
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var notificationMessage = "Oops, there are no more user cards to display";
var userIndex = 0;
var undoBtn = $("#button")
var $clearBtn = $("#clear");
var $contentArea = $("#content");


var cardTemplate =  '<div class="card" data-id="{id}"><div class="title"><div class="image"></div><div class="name">{name}</div><button onclick="removeUser({postid})" class="close"></button></div><div class="description">{body}<a href="mailto:" class="email">{email}</a></div></div>';
```

//  - Load all the card at once, when screen load

```
 $(function() {
      $contentArea.append(renderUser);
    });
```

// Make array from usercards

```
 var $cardDiv = $(".card");
 var usersCardArray = $cardDiv.toArray(); // return usersCardArray.length = 0 :(
```

//remove all card at once

```
$clearBtn.click(clearUsers);

function clearUsers () {
  $contentArea.empty();
  userIndex = 0;
}
```

//remove one card

```
$('.card .close').on('click', removeUser);

function removeUser(postId) {
  $('[data-id="'  + postId + '"]').remove();
}
```

// get user data

```
function getUser () {
      return $.ajax({ url: root + '/posts/1/comments', method: 'GET' });
    }



 function renderUser() {
      getUser().then(function (user) {
         for (var i = 0; i = user.length; i++) {
          var card = cardTemplate
            .replace('{id}', user[userIndex].id)
            .replace('{postid}', user[userIndex].id)
            .replace('{name}', user[userIndex].name)
            .replace('{body}', user[userIndex].body)
            .replace('{email}', user[userIndex].email);

            $contentArea.append(card);
            userIndex++;
        }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't manipulate any actual data, only the view itself - you can add class `.hidden` on delete card, and remove this class on undo.

To keep track on deleted users I added array `var deletedUsers =[]`. Each time you delete a user, add its id to array and hide it from view by adding class `hidden`.

On undo - pop the user id from `deletedUsers`, and remove class `hidden` from this user's card

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbXxrB

Comment: Thanks, but I need to restore removed card one by one, in your case if I delete 3 items, all three are back.

Comment: If I deleted 2 users for example, clicking on Undo twice should restore both of them one by one? Or only last deleted user can be restored?

Comment: So keep track of the items removed.